# Backbone: How to trigger methods in a parent view

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I have an alphabet filter view (a, b, c, d etc) that a lot of views will be using. I have setup a method on the main view to fetch results from the API using the letter clicked.

I've setup this by passing a callback function down to the alphabet filter as per below:

```
view = new App.Views.Common.AlphabetFiltersIndexView(filterCallback: @paginationFilter)
@$(".pagination-vertical").replaceWith(view.render().el)
```

Calling the filterCallback and passing arguments works, however the paginationFilter method called now belongs to the Alphabet Filters.

Question: How do I call a parent view's method and keep the method's relationship with the original top view?

Answer (score 4):

You could go about this two ways:

1. Pass the parent view to your child view, OR have your child view find its parent via a global object, if you're using one.  Call the parent view's function from the child
2. You could have your child view raise an event when you need the parent view's function to be called.  Your parent view should be listening for this event from your child view, and respond by calling the method required.

Comment: I'm developing a small app using the #2 method you described. Are there any structural or performance issues I should take into account when using an event-driven approach?

Comment: @Prefix I would just ensure that you unbind your event listeners when you destroy a parent/child view. I don't think there's a whole lot to it.  That said, I haven't done much backbone development in over a year. Not sure how the landscape has changed.

Answer (score 4):

You should trigger an event in the child view using something like

```
this.trigger('event', [args]);
```

and listen to it from the parent view

```
this.listenTo(childView, 'event', this.paginationFilter);
```

(Recommend giving the event a proper name. Consider a name such as 'page:change'. 'page' is a sort of namespace just to make the events in large application easier to name and organize. There is no real namespace functionality.)

Comment: Note, if it's an event that only needs to be responded to a single time, you can also use the `listenToOnce()`, which will unbind itself after intercepting one event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Underscore call in your `AlphabetFiltersIndexView` in it's`initialize` method

```
_.bindAll(callBackContext, "YourCallBack");
```

This will ensure the callback is bound to the object of your choice (The parent view).

You can pass in the values of `callBackContext` and `"YourCallBack"` as parameters to the `AlphabetFiltersIndexView`, which you can then control based on the context of the parent view.